# Python script that takes two lists of integers as inputs and returns subset of the second list that are within one unit in the first list?

Tags: python, list, bioinformatics

This is what I have so far:

```
list1= raw_input('Enter first list of integers, with comma after each number: ')
list2 = raw_input('Enter second list of integers, with comma after each number: ')
list1 = list1.split(',') #makes lists
list2 = list2.split(',')

list1 = (int(x) for x in list1) #turns them into integers
list2 = (int(x) for x in list2)

secondlist = []

for x in list2:
    if x == 
while x in list2 == list1[x]+1 or list1[x]-1:
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to have it check *every* item in list1 with one item in list2.

Comment: your question is unclear can you explain more about the problem? its good that add an example and expected out out to your question!

Comment: So you want to check if element from element from list1 exists in list2 than ?

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the second list, then loop through the first, checking if the absolute value of the two numbers is 0 or 1 and add to the result list if true.

Example:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [4, 5, 7, 0, 75]
matches = []
for i2 in l2:
    for i1 in l1:
        if abs(i1 - i2) <= 1:
            matches.append(i2)
            break
```

`matches` is `[4, 5, 0]`

If you're interested in a one-liner:

```
[y for y in l2 if any(abs(x - y) <= 1 for x in l1)]
```

Implementing this with your code would look like

```
list1 = raw_input('Enter first list of integers, with comma after each number: ').split(',')
list2 = raw_input('Enter second list of integers, with comma after each number: ').split(',')
list1 = map(int, list1)
list2 = map(int, list2)
secondlist = [y for y in l2 if any(abs(x - y) <= 1 for x in l1)]
```

Comment: `abs(i1 - i2) <= 1` is more clear. Equivalent here since they're integers, but...

Comment: Fair enough; I agree.

Comment: This is a O(n^2) algorithm. It works, but the time required to compute the result will increase significantly when the lists are long.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's not SUPER simple, but you could do it in two list comprehensions.

```
import itertools

# lst1 and 2 are already ints

valid_numbers = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable([(num-1, num, num+1) for num in lst1]))
result = [num for num in lst2 if num in valid_numbers]
```

This will only loop through `lst1` twice and `lst2` once, rather than looping through `lst1` N times (once per element in `lst2`). Because of this, it should be much quicker as `lst2` grows.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Let's suppose you already have the lists
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5, 2,3,4, 2]


# Count occurences
occurences = {}
for item in list2:
    if item in occurences:
        occurences[item]+=1
    else:
        occurences[item]=1

ones = set([])
for item in list1:
    if (occurences.get(item+1,0)>0) or (occurences.get(item-1,0)>0):
        ones.add(item)
print ones
```

Comment: You can simplify the dictionary setting to `occurences[item] = occurences.get(item, 0) + 1`. Then you won't need the if/else.

Comment: I suppose, dictionary hashing has constant computation time (regardless of its size), so this algorithm computes in O(n), because it iterates over a list and another.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "within one unit in the first list"? The following is my understanding of this sentence.

```
def within_one(xlist, x):
    within = False
    for i in xlist:
        if x >= i-1 and x =< i+1:
            within = True
            break
    return within

print([j for j in list2 if within_one(list1, j)])
```

Comment: `within_one` is incorrectly indented, but the whole function is just `return any(abs(x - y) <= 1 for y in xlist)`

Answer (score 0):

More or less the same as the absolute value based one-liner above, but a little more understandable to me at a glance.

```
>>> lst1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> lst2 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> [n for n in lst2 if n in lst1 or n+1 in lst1 or n-1 in lst1]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: This also works, but the "in" operator for lists can be slow if the list is long. It is because the in operator has to go over the list, so I believe this computes in O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

This one should be O(2n*(1+log(n))): sorting the input lists takes O(n log(n)) per list and then both lists are traversed exactly once, O(n).

```
mk_nm    = lambda nm: "Enter {0}> ".format( nm )
readlist = lambda nm: sorted(map(int, raw_input(mk_nm(nm)).strip().split(',')))

# read the input lists and transform them into sorted lists of ints
list1    = readlist("list1")
list2    = readlist("list2")

# The accumulator holds the output list and 
# the current list1
def reductor(acc, l2item):
    (output, l1) = acc
    # process elements from l1 until we find one
    # that is > current l2 item-1
    for i in xrange(len(l1)):
        if abs(l1[i] - l2item)<=1:
            output.append(l2item)
        if l1[i]>=l2item-1:
            break
    # remove elements from l1 that we processed
    return (output, l1[i:])

found = reduce(reductor, list2, ([], list1))[0]
print "Found: ",found
```

Trying it:

```
Enter list1> 1,2,3,4
Enter list2> 4,5,7,0,70
Found:  [0, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score -1):

editing original answer...
A double list comprehension would work for this.  As an algorithm it is O(n^2).

```
list1 = [10, 20, 30, 40]
list2 = [8, 21, 32, 39]

print [x for x in list2 for y in list1 if abs(x-y) <= 1]
```

If you find that the lists you are comparing are very large, or if you set up list1 a single time and you repeatedly search it with list2 or other lists, you may consider switching to a dictionary, also known as a hash table.

```
l1 = [x+1 for x in list1] #Just building the lists
l2 = [x-1 for x in list1] #
list1.extend(l1)
list1.extend(l2)  #list1 now has x, x-1, and x+1 for each x

d = dict(zip(list1, list1))

print [x for x in list2 if x in d]
```

The dictionary will be O(n) for building the dictionary in the first place and then have average O(1) searching after that.  Something to consider.

Comment: eek this is a silly way to do this! You're checking membership in a list a *whole* lot of times, and don't even include the possibility that `x in list1`. Not to mention you don't actually return any data, just print `"Yes"` or `"No"` to stdout

Comment: No disagreement here.  It was a strange question.

Comment: Actually, @AdamSmith.  Your algorithm is O(3n^2) = O(n^2) and mine is O(2n^2) = O(n^2).  I was just trying to fix the OP's syntax.  Not really sure why you down voted me.